# Read in multiple data frames and restructure using a loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have several data frames with the same structure (different iterations). I would like to read in the data from each iteration and restructure using dplyr. Then compile the restructured output into a single data frame. I think the best way to do this is via looping but I haven't had success creating one.

I have 5 datasets just like the below.

```
> df.0
   v1          v2       v3       v4  v5 v6 v7
1   0 -3.82029420 31.81448 301.4946 180 42 21
2   1 -3.57029420 31.81448 301.4946 188 35 21
3   2 -3.32029420 31.81448 301.4946 196 30 21
4   3 -3.07029420 31.81448 301.4946 204 25 21


df.1
   v1           v2       v3       v4  v5 v6 v7
1   0 -3.826521174 31.81448 301.4946 180 43 21
2   1 -3.576521174 31.81448 301.4946 188 36 21
3   2 -3.326521174 31.81448 301.4946 196 30 21
4   3 -3.076521174 31.81448 301.4946 204 25 21
```

I would like to read each one in and perform this restructuring.

```
rs.0 = df.0 %>% 
  group_by(v7) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!v7 == 21) %>%
  mutate(Level = ifelse(v7 == 22, "II",
                        ifelse(v7 == 23, "III",
                               ifelse(v7 == 24, "IV", NA))),
         iteration = 0)  %>%
  dplyr::select(iteration, v1, v7) %>%
  spread(key = "Level", value = "v1")
```

Then rbind the output into a single dataframe with a row for each iteration that looks like this:

```
A tibble: 2 x 4
  iteration    II   III    IV
*     <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1         0    19    29    40
2         1    19    28    39
```

Comment: I would start by examining the map_dfr functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you could investigate making your dataframes into a list:

`dfList = list(df.0,df.1,df.2,df.3.df.4)`

Then using `lapply` in conjunction with a function that does the restructuring:

`newList = lapply(dfList,functionYouShouldMake)`

Then you can rbind them all together with `do.call` (I think). Something along the lines of:

`goodDF = do.call(rbind,newList)`

NB there are some problems with your restructuring code. `filter(!v7 == 21)` gets rid of all your rows in the example dataframes, unless those are just the first few rows? In any case it would be nice to have better example data.

Also this can't work

> ```r
> dplyr::select(iteration, v1, v7) %>%
>  spread(key = "Level", value = "v1")
> ```

Because `select` gets rid of `Level` before `spread` calls it.

Comment: Also specifying the iteration number is hard to do when looping through a list (probably not that hard but I'm not very good at this). If I were you I would just `rbind` an iteration column once you've made your table.